# How to use a --proxy-server flag in Chromium browser

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, c++

I am attempting to use the --proxy-server flag in the Chromium source code on Windows like this:

--proxy-server=protocol://username:password@host:port

However, when I run any website on Chromium, it gives me the error "ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXY". But if I use the flag like this:

--proxy-server="host:port"

and open any website, it opens a prompt box to fill a username and password. After filling the username and password, it works properly.

However, I don't want to fill this username and password every time when i run any website on Chromium. Is there a way to fill the username and password through the flag so that the proxy flag works properly without requiring manual input?

I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to properly use the --proxy-server flag in the Chromium source code. Thank you in advance for your assistance.